# Relevance of question on carrying cash on hand

Tags: discussion

Is a question about "whether or not carrying a large sum of cash-on-hand in the United States is a good idea or too risky" a good fit for this site?

I just want to make sure I'm not about to post a question that would be closed/DV'd for being off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

It's not really a personal finance question, more a travel safety question... The answer depends on where and how much you are talking about, and what alternatives are available to you, and how worried you are...

I think https://travel.stackexchange.com/ is a better match and will give you better answers for this question.

Comment: +1, thanks for answering. Exactly what I was thinking. Not really PF